# How to start and stop function using getter and setter?

Tags: ios, xcode

In .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
            @private int intVariable1;
    }
    @property (readwrite,assign) int iVar;

    -(void)Callme;
    @end
```

In .m file

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize iVar=intVariable1;

-(void)Callme
{
        NSLog(@”Callme called”);
}

-(void)setIVar:(int)inIVar
{
        intVariable1 = inIVar;
        [self Callme];
}
@end
```

I have implement this code to call "Callme" function when the variable state changes, But when i call the function setIVar in  viewDid load it does not work, Any idea of calling this?
Way i used to call

```
[self setIVar:3];
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly declaring that setter?

Comment: Dear sir, I m bit new to Objective C and coding, What do you mean by explicitly declaring of the setter? Thank you!

Comment: Your implementation has a different name than your interface.  Why is that?

Comment: Replace the `readwrite` part of the property declaration (which is completely unnecessary) with `setter=` then the name of your setter function.

Comment: @borrrden - It's mistake. I corrected it! Thank u!

Comment: @CodaFi he is directly calling the method (bypassing any synthesis) so will it really make a difference?  I think something else is at play here...

Comment: @property (setter =setIVar:,assign) int iVar;
But it produce no results! :(

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line you call the method, and see if it stops.  If it does, hit F7 over and over to see what happens in the execution.

Comment: This code works perfectly fine in a small test app, perhaps the code that calls the setter isn't being run.

Comment: Yes both are correct. setter doesn't get call, With F7 thread continues for ever with no result! Strange!

Comment: @borrrden - It's not getting called? Any reason for that?

Comment: Lots of reasons, too many to guess.  Need some more info about your code.  Where you are calling it (in what class), and how that class is being used (XIB?)

Comment: According to the information that you have given, your code works fine(I tested that). You need to give more info of your code..

Comment: @borrrden - I m calling it inside -(void)viewDidLoad{[self setIVar:3]; } simple as that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide your own implementation for getter/setter functions *do not* use the `@synthesize` directive in your implementation! This will generate its own `-(void)setIVar:(int)inIVar` and `-(int)iVar` methods and these might hide your version. In turn, if you want a `readwrite` property, you'll also have to implement the getter i.e. `-(int)iVar`.

Simple remove the `@synthesize iVar=intVariable1;` line from your implementation and put implement also `-(int)iVar`.

Comment: They will not hide your version.  In fact if you only define a setter or getter then you *must* synthesize (assuming read write).  The compiler knows not to generate methods if they already exist.

Comment: :O... People keeps me down voting my question and still i wonder what is the best solution for it! :) Thank you for your answer, What you say to @borrrden answer?

Comment: if @borrrden is right, then there will be some other problem with the way you're using the methods. Consider posting more code if there're any more relevant pieces.